# MySql calculate average grade

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and have 2 tables.

[image]

What I need is an average grade of all reviews of that organizations. My question is, should I make a trigger and a procedure to allways update average grade on insert or just calculate it when needed? I am going to need it multiple (5-10) times on each page.

Comment: Calculate it when you need it

Comment: What if I have few thousand's of reviews on each organization? Should I still do it when need it? I dont want my page to load slowly because of database calculation delay? but I neither want to do so many calculations on every update/insert/delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A general rule of thumb: Premature optimization are the mother of all evil. Start with calculating the average whenever you need it. If that becomes too slow, you can start thinking about optimizations such as caching it or pre-calculating it and saving it to the database (e.g., by a trigger, like you proposed).